# How does this CombineWords work/reads?

Tags: java, string

I'm new here and not very well versed with programming but am here to learn. I understand the simple loop for ( initialisation ; termination ; increment/decrements ) but not familiar with this one.

What does this initialisation and termination means in the for loop? How am I supposed to read this in literal?

1. I pass through an argument say  words[0] = I words,[1] = love, words[2]= apple
2. sentence is assigned to ""
3. w = words[0]
4. sentence += w + " "
5. w = words[1]
6. sentence += w + " "
7. w = words[2]
8. ...
9. terminate

> ```
> public static String CombineWords(String[] words) {
>     String sentence = "";
>     for (String w : words) {
>         sentence += w + " ";
>     }
>     return sentence;
> }
> ```

And here how does this delimiting "[ ]+" works? Say I pass "I love apple"

```
/**
 * Parses a sentence into an array of words
 * @param sentence the string sentence to parse
 * @return an array of words (in the sentence)
 */
public static String[] GetWords(String sentence) {
    return sentence.split("[ ]+");
}
```

Comment: `[ ]+` is called a regular expression. It means 1 or more spaces. You are splitting the string on whitespace

Comment: off topics: clueless why character-class is used in the regex.  Simply a `" +"` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking about how the for loop works when declared like this:

```
for (String w : words) {
```

Basically, it iterates through the values in words, storing the current value of each iteration in the w variable.

So...

```
for (String w : words) {
    sentence += w + " ";
}
```

is like shorthand for

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    String w = words[i];
    sentence += w + " ";
}
```

In the background, it actually produces an Iterator and uses that, but that's not particularly important/interesting for a beginner.